# How to save survey progress for a user

Tags: symfony

hi i'm doing a survey i could record the progress of the quiz according to the user

example: user is at question 15/50 he must be able to disconnect and continue where he was stopping.

I manage to assign the answers to the user, but not to worry about the progress. thank you so much

so here I got my answer via the post method
my controlleur to save answer for a user..

```
class DefaultController extends Controller

{

     /**
     * @Route("/Reponse/thematique", name="thematique_reponse")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */

    public function reponseThematique(Request $request)

    {
            //instance des repository
            $userSlpRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(UserSlp::class);
            $reponseThematiqueRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Reponse_thematique::class);
            $questionMangerRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Manger::class);//here all the questions

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $userSlp = $userSlpRepo->findOneByGaeaUserId($this->getUser()->getId());
            $datas = $request->request->all();


           foreach ($datas as $data => $value ){
            $question = $questionMangerRepo->find($data);  

            $answer = new Reponse_thematique;
            $answer->setManger($question); 
            $answer->setValue($value); 
            $answer->setUserSlp($userSlp);          
            $em->persist($answer); 
            $em->flush();
           }

     return new response('ok');

    }
```

I thought to make a relationship with an entity "questionnaire-progress" for example or we will have an id, question_id, user_id and why not a column or we would put a boolean if the questionaire is finished or not.

```
/**
 * SurveyProgress
 *

 * @ORM\Table(name="survey_progress", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_7EF6B461B3FE509D",
 *  columns={"questionnaire_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_7EF6B4611E27F6BF",
 *  columns={"manger_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_7EF6B461FDDFEACC",
 *  columns={"userSlp_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class QuestionnaireProgress
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="done", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $done;

    /**
     * @var \Question
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="manger")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $manger;

    /**
     * @var \Survey
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="questionnaire")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="questionnaire_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $questionnaire;

    /**
     * @var \UserSlp
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserSlp")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userSlp_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $userslp;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the answers everytime the user answers. Then, you'll have this information stored.

I suppose a `Survey` contains a list of `Question`s. You can then get the total number of questions.

If you save the answers when the user answers, the number of `Reponse_thematique` for a given `UserSlp` and a given `Survey` / the total number of questions will give you the progress